# Looking for a simple free smtp server

Tags: windows-server-2003, smtp

I have a client looking for a decent free mail server for Windows 2k2 R2. They are looking at sending mail mostly but if receiving is possible that is a plus. I know that Windows comes with smtp but I am looking around at other options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best simple SMTP I would recommend would be hmailserver ( http://www.hmailserver.com )

This is a greatly expandable program, but also ridiculously straightforward, and it has a large online help forum, etc.

It doesn't require anything on the server side, not even a DB if you choose to use the built in db.

I have great amount of experience with this as I've used it in the past in my business, so help is free, fast and simple if you have any direct questions about it from me.

Comment: Perfect was exactly what I was looking for.